# What is the event available for canceling editing?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I want to do something when the author opens a page, makes some changes and closes without saving.

I am expecting an event like close or cancel, but I can't find any event like that.

Which event should I subscribe to in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no close or cancel event and since the user did not perform a save there is no event called at all (unless it is an existing item, then the close would trigger an undo-checkout). Please note that the user does get a warning when he tries to close a window without saving, so it is considered a conscious decision here.

Your only way to interact with this would be through a UI extension, but it would be interesting to know a bit more about the use case to see if it actually makes sense to go down that route (a UI extension is nontrivial).